Invocable Variable not showing on Screen Flow
I have a screen flow that makes use of an invocable method. The method returns List<List<Response>>, being the Response constructor like this:
public class Response {
        @InvocableVariable @AuraEnabled
        public Account pdvVinculado;

        @InvocableVariable @AuraEnabled
        public Account pdvVinculable;

        @InvocableVariable @AuraEnabled
        public Account pdvNoVinculable;
        
        public Response(Account pdvVinculado, Account pdvVinculable, Account pdvNoVinculable) {
            this.pdvVinculado = pdvVinculado;
            this.pdvVinculable = pdvVinculable;
            this.pdvNoVinculable = pdvNoVinculable;
        }
    }

After the method call I loop through its records and in a decision element I should be able to select "Current item from loop -> pdvVinculado".
I have tried making the variables and constructor global, setting a label for each variable but still nothing is showing up in the decision element.
What is missing?
Edit:
This is the whole class:
/**
@description
Clase controladora para gestionar los Puntos de Venta que se van a vincular en el flujo de pantalla

FECHA       AUTOR       DESCRIPCION<br/>
07/11/2024  LCS-JP          Creación

@author Leadclic Solutions
*/
public class MSM_VincularPdVsController {

    /**
     * @description: Método Invocable para realizar gestionar los datos a mostrar en un flujo de pantalla           
     * @param List<String> recordsId
     */
    @InvocableMethod(label= 'PdVs clasificados por estado de disponibilidad')
    public static List<List<Response>> getPdVsByAvailability(List<String> recordsId) {
        //1. Inicializamos estructuras de datos que vamos a gestionar
        List<List<Response>> lstToReturnFinal = new List<List<Response>>();
        List<Response> lstToReturn = new List<Response>();
        List<Account> lstAllPdVs = new List<Account>();
        List<MSM_Prestamo_PdV__c> lstAllPrestamoPdVs = new List<MSM_Prestamo_PdV__c>();
        Map<Id, List<MSM_Prestamo_PdV__c>> mapHandler = new Map<Id, List<MSM_Prestamo_PdV__c>>();
        MSM_Prestamo__c prestamo = new MSM_Prestamo__c();
        
        //2. Consultamos datos necesarios
        //2.1 Consulta del prestamo del flujo
        prestamo = [SELECT Id, MSM_TipoContrato__c, MSM_Cadena__c FROM MSM_Prestamo__c WHERE Id = :recordsId[0]];
        //2.2 Consulta de PdVs asociados a la cadena
        lstAllPdVs = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE ParentId = :prestamo.MSM_Cadena__c];
        //2.3 Consulta de PdV-Prestamo asociados a la cadena
        lstAllPrestamoPdVs = [SELECT Id, MSM_PdV__c, MSM_Prestamo__c, MSM_Prestamo__r.MSM_TipoContrato__c FROM MSM_Prestamo_PdV__c WHERE MSM_PdV__c IN :lstAllPdVs];

        //3. Bucle para rellenar el mapa
        for(MSM_Prestamo_PdV__c record : lstAllPrestamoPdVs) {
            if(mapHandler.get(record.MSM_PdV__c) != null) {
                mapHandler.get(record.MSM_PdV__c).add(record);
            }else {
                mapHandler.put(record.MSM_PdV__c, new List<MSM_Prestamo_PdV__c>{record});
            }
        }
        
        //4. Bucle para rellenar las listas que se muestran en el flujo
        for(Account record : lstAllPdVs) {
            if(mapHandler.get(record.Id) != null) {
                Response resp = new Response(null, null, null);
                Boolean isVinculado = false;
                Boolean isVinculable = false;
                Boolean isNoVinculable = false;
                //4.1 Si el PdV tiene algún préstamo
                for(MSM_Prestamo_PdV__c auxRecord : mapHandler.get(record.Id)) {
                    //4.1.1 Si el PdV tiene algún préstamo, y es el mismo préstamo del flujo
                    if(auxRecord.MSM_Prestamo__c == prestamo.Id) {
                        isVinculado = true;
                    } 
                    //4.1.2 Si el PdV tiene algún préstamo, y no es el mismo préstamo del flujo
                    //4.1.2.1 Si el PdV tiene algún préstamo, y no es el mismo préstamo del flujo y no tiene ningún préstamo más del mismo tipo
                    else if(prestamo.MSM_TipoContrato__c != auxRecord.MSM_Prestamo__r.MSM_TipoContrato__c && !isNoVinculable) {
                        isVinculable = true;
                    }
                    //4.1.2.2 Si el PdV tiene algún préstamo, y no es el mismo préstamo del flujo y tiene algún préstamo más del mismo tipo
                    else {
                        isNoVinculable = true;
                    }
                }
                
                //4.1.3 Rellenamos las listas correspondientes
                if(isVinculado) {
                    resp.pdvVinculado = record;
                    lstToReturn.add(resp);
                }else if(isNoVinculable) {
                    resp.pdvNoVinculable = record;
                    lstToReturn.add(resp);
                }else {
                    resp.pdvVinculable = record;
                    lstToReturn.add(resp);
                }
            }else {
                Response resp = new Response(null, null, null);
                resp.pdvVinculable = record;
                //4.2 Si el PdV no tiene ningún préstamo, es un PdV vinculable
                lstToReturn.add(resp);
            }
        }
        lstToReturnFinal.add(lstToReturn);
        System.debug('JP lstToReturn ' + lstToReturn);
        return lstToReturnFinal;
    }
    
    public class Response {
        @InvocableVariable @AuraEnabled
        public Account pdvVinculado;

        @InvocableVariable @AuraEnabled
        public Account pdvVinculable;

        @InvocableVariable @AuraEnabled
        public Account pdvNoVinculable;
        
        
        public Response(Account pdvVinculado, Account pdvVinculable, Account pdvNoVinculable) {
            this.pdvVinculado = pdvVinculado;
            this.pdvVinculable = pdvVinculable;
            this.pdvNoVinculable = pdvNoVinculable;
        }
    }
}


I believe the following two points are relevant: 1. You need a default constructor and 2. I don't believe you can set a value both @InvocableVariable and @AuraEnabled; invocable variables must be public/global attributes (like you have here) while aura enabled values must be public/global properties (with getters/setters).

(There are some scenarios where an aura enabled value can be an attribute, but you can hit unexpected errors if you use this approach.)

I tried removing the @AuraEnabled anootation or even changing the return type of the moethod to List but still no change

@PhilW I have edited the question to show the whole class.

There are two points to note here:

You should ensure the class as an accessible default constructor since this seems to be needed to allow the runtime to manage the data appropriately, constructing and populating records.
Salesforce doesn't officially support marking attributes/properties as both @InvocableVariable and @AuraEnabled.

According to the documentation:

@InvocableVariable values need to be accessible attributes ("class member variables") on the Apex class.
@AuraEnabled values need to be accessible properties on the Apex class.

You can sometimes get away with using attributes for @AuraEnabled values, as discussed here, but you can find things don't work correctly if you do.
My suggestion:

Remove the @AuraEnabled annotations.
Add a default constructor.

Additionally, make sure your types abide by the documentation:

Other annotations can’t be used with the InvocableVariable annotation.


The data type of the invocable variable must be one of these:

A primitive other than Object
An sObject, either the generic sObject or a specific sObject
A list or a list of lists of primitives, sObjects, objects created from Apex classes, or collections


Clearly you will need to refresh the flow builder once you have made the required changes.

This still hasn't worked, aI have removed the aura annotation, you can see that there is a constructor defined for the invocable variables and they aren't showing yet when I try to loop over the collection

Your question still shows that there is no default constructor for the Response class. A default constructor is one with no arguments.

I erased the Response constructor, the @AuraEnabled annotation and the variables aren't showing yet. They are still unreachable.
